# Need Help Connecting OpenAI Text-to-Speech API with React Native

Tags: react-native, chatbot, openai-api

I hope you're all doing well! I've been diving into the new OpenAI Text-to-Speech API, and I'm currently stuck trying to connect it with my React Native project. I've been scouring the documentation, but I'm still a bit lost.

Has anyone successfully integrated the OpenAI Text-to-Speech API with React Native? If so, could you share some insights or point me in the right direction? I've tried a few approaches, but I seem to be missing a crucial step.

Are there any specific libraries or packages that work well with React Native and the OpenAI Text-to-Speech API?

When I call the API, I receive JSON data, but I'm unsure how to incorporate this information into the audio library for playback.

https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio/createSpeech

[image]

When I call the API, I receive JSON data, but I'm unsure how to incorporate this information into the audio library for playback.